# MongoDB - Load a subset of documents for querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, nosql

I have a collection containing multiple clients, months, etc.

Each month I need to run a series of queries against the collection to retrieve metrics - basically a bunch of counts.

Most of those queries have the same 4 or 5 filters, with an additional 1-2 filters that change for each query.

```
//standard filters:

{ client: "ABC Corp",
  environment: "Production",
  device: "true",
  registered: "true"
}

//special filters:

{ type: "typeA",
  screen: "screen1"   }

{ type: "typeA",
  screen: "screen2"   }
```

In MSSQL I would create a view containing the 4 standard filters, and query that view repeatedly, applying the additional 1-2 filters to retrieve the needed metrics.

Any suggestions about what MongoDB or basic JS approach I could use for this? My goal is to avoid hitting the collection over and over again with those same standard filters.

Thanks
V

Answer (score 0):

You could use $out operator in aggregation framework to achieve this.

> [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage can output results into a new collection

For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match:
      {
        client: "ABC Corp",
        environment: "Production",
        device: "true",
        registered: "true"
      }
  },
  {
    $out: "new_collection"
  }
])
```

Then you can run your additional queries on the **new_collection**.

Your "view" collection will be recreated every time when you use it in $out stage but any indexes you defined on that collection will be left intact.